# Determine coefficient λ so vectors p and q are mutually perpendicular

Tags: vectors

> p=λa+17b
>
> q=3a-b
>
> |a|=2 , |b|=5 , angle between a & b vector is 120°

I got for vectors a and b

$$
\vec{a}=(-1,\sqrt{3}) \vec{b}=(\frac{-5}{2},\tfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{2})\
$$

how do I find coefficient λ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: we get
$$\vec{p}\cdot \vec{q}=3\lambda\vec{a}^2+51\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}-\lambda\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}-17\vec{b}^2$$
and use that $$\vec{x}^2=|\vec{x}|^2$$